# return unit instead of int array

Tags: ocaml, typeerror

I have the following code:

```
let rec dec_to_bin a b c =
  match a with
  | 0 -> b
  | _ -> if a mod 2 = 0 then dec_to_bin (a/2)(b)(c+1) else b.(c) <- 1;dec_to_bin ((a-1)/2)(b)(c+1);;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type
         int array
```

I think the problem comes from the fact that the compiler only executes: `b.(c) <- 1;` and hence thinks that this is `unit` type.
Yet does it mean that I can't execute two things in a pattern matching?

So how can I make this code work?

Comment: What are a, b and c initially?

Comment: a is an int, b an array and c an int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is because `if` has a higher precedence than `;` (you can see the table of precedence by going [here](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec128) and scrolling up a little bit). So the `if ... else ...` is only interpreted as going up to the `;`. If you want to execute multiple "statements" as the `else` expression, then you will have to wrap them in either parentheses, `( ... )`, or `begin ... end` (they are the same).

Comment: Tip: Use an editor that automatically indents ocaml and use lots of newlines., certainly after every ";". The indent would show you that you left the else branch.